# Two composite foreign keys with one column in common

Tags: sql, postgresql, entity-relationship

I am trying to map the following ER Model into PostgreSQL and I am having trouble with the **Issue_Label** table. It requires the key from the **Issue** table, which is *id* and the key from the **Label** table, which is the pair *(id, project_id)*.

[image: ER Model]
However, I wanna make sure the *project_id* from both the **Issue** table (which is not part of the primary key) and the **Label** table are the same.
I tried the following:

```
CREATE TABLE issue_label (
    issue_id UUID,
    label_name TEXT,
    project_id UUID,
    FOREIGN KEY (issue_id, project_id) REFERENCES issue(id, project_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (label_name, project_id) REFERENCES label(name, project_id),
    PRIMARY KEY (issue_id, label_name, project_id)
);
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "issue"
SQL state: 42830
```

How can I fix this, preferably without having to change the **Issue** table key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If:

- The key from the `Issue` table is `id`, and
- The key from the `Label` table is the pair (`id`, `project_id`)

Then the foreign keys should take the form:

```
CREATE TABLE issue_label (
    issue_id UUID,
    label_name TEXT,
    project_id UUID,
    FOREIGN KEY (issue_id) REFERENCES issue(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (issue_id, project_id) REFERENCES label(id, project_id),
    PRIMARY KEY (issue_id, label_name, project_id)
);
```

Comment: I understand that, but Issue also has a "project_id", even though it's not part of the primary key, and I still wanna make sure it's the same as the one from the Label foreign key. How should I do that?

Comment: @GoncaloNGT If `project_id` is not part of a key (primary or other), then you cannot use it for a foreign key; you won't be able to enforce it's the same project this way. If you need to enforce it at the database level, then add the `project_id` as part of the primary key of `Issue`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I guess I can't avoid that then